# Jquery DateTimePicker not displaying with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using the DateTimePicker found here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ (note that I get the same problem described below if I use the default DatePicker within Jquery as well).

I have checked that I have the appropriate CSS, images, version of jquery installed/reinstalled many times and I cannot seem to find what is causing my DateTimePicker to look like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/D1t78]

If I remove all CSS (including my site's default MVC CSS) I lose the blue background to the days of the week (aren't these supposed to be colored by the Jquery UI theme?).

Where do I need to look to solve my problem?

Edit to show my code:

This is the PartialView I am rendering within my page:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FillCourseForm.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="CourseFormFields">
<p>the string is @ViewBag.selectedString</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyToTeach", "Course", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And the Jquery:

```
$("#StartDate").datetimepicker({
    ampm: true
});
```

The generated HTML (truncated a bit to prevent massive wall of code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ApplyToTeach</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
       <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>St. Paul School of Catechesis</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

            </div>
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Student">Students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Course">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Instructor">Instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="originalForm">
<link href="themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/FillCourseForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="CourseFormFields">
<p>the string is </p>
<form action="/Course/ApplyToTeach" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>CourseTemplates</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="StartDate">StartDate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StartDate field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StartDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form></div>
</div>
<div id ="divToAppend">
</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a stylesheet needed that isn't being applied. This could be for any number of reasons, such as a bad link to the CSS file or duplicate IDs in your HTML. Can you please post some actual code for us to look at.

Comment: Added code, id issues in HTML seems interesting . . .  I am using Razor markup to generate the field that the user clicks on to get the popup. . .  can that cause problems?

Comment: It would be preferable if you posted the generated HTML the browser sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making this a second answer since my first has good point for your code.

If you notice in your PartialView, you use Url.Content paths for your scripts and css. However, you aren't using a path from the root for your jquery-ui.custom.css path as you are with your scripts. Note...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I believe it should instead be...(replace with the appropriate path to the CSS - I always put my CSS in the /Content folder in my project).

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the required files for the datepicker and include them into your page.

http://jqueryui.com/download

ui core and the datepicker widget

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not answer your question, but, after taking a look at your code, your HTML is fairly messy in the sense that you are including JavaScript and CSS within the body of your HTML. This does not guarantee that the browser will properly execute it.

Instead, I would recommend either including the JavaScript and CSS within a _Layout page in the header as appropriate, or, at the very least, create a section within your header so that you can ensure proper placement when you reference it in your partial view. Here's an example...

In your _Layout:

```
<head>
  <!-- Put your links and scripts first. -->
  <link ...>
  <script ...>
  <!-- Then make sure you include this. -->
  @RenderSection("Header", false)
</head>
```

Then, in your partial view, you can do this:

```
@* At the top of your partial view *@
@section Header {
<link href="@Url.Content("themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FillCourseForm.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

When the HTML renders, you will find that those script and link tags have now been placed in the Header section which is appropriate HTML.

Comment: Good points, thank you.  Does not fix the original problem though.