# jQuery datetime picker not rendering CSS file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the jQuery datetime picker with ASP.Net MVC3. For some reason, although the datetimepicker shows up, the stylesheet doesn't render properly.

(I'd post a photo but I'm new here, so I'll describe it instead since I can't post photos)

When I click on the textbox that's supposed to fire the datetime picker, much like the default example shown for the jQuery demo it opens the calendar view, but the background is missing and the text "prevnext" shows up above the month and year so it looks transparent against the rest of the form that it's on top of. Similar to this post - [Jquery DateTimePicker not displaying with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229668/jquery-datetimepicker-not-displaying-with-css) but I don't even get the blue background.

The answer at this post : [Jquery DateTimePicker not displaying with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229668/jquery-datetimepicker-not-displaying-with-css) was for partial views and not full views and the solution did not help me, so I'm wondering if there's anything different for full views.

I have the following code in Site.Master:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css") %>" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css") %>" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datePicker.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dp").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my content page (view) the control is declared like this:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthday" runat="server" class="dp" />
```

I also have another existing style sheet declared specifically to set the layout of the page:

```
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And finally, a helper viewcontrol to identify the textboxes that are set as datetimepickers:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
```

```
<%: Html.TextBox("",  String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp"})%>
```

Can anyone help me with why the CSS is not rendering?

Comment: DUDE! DUDE, dude, dude ... dude. Don't use jQueryUI directly with ASP.Net apps. Not saying you cant, there are work arounds, but you will run into one problem after another. Just get regular jQuery and then go [HERE](http://juiceui.com/).  It's called [JuiceUI](http://juiceui.com/) and it is basically jQueryUI FOR ASP.NET!!! DUDE! Go! Go! Go! See [JuiceUI DatePicker Here](http://juiceui.com/controls/datepicker)!!!

Comment: Did you try to see what "developer tool" shows in your view? Try to find what CSS rules are present...

Comment: @SpYk3HH I checked out JuiceUI and the datepicker works great! Is there a specific stylesheet I can tweak for datepicker colors?

Comment: basically JuiceUI *uses* [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). So if you want a different them, you create it at jQueryUI, then download it and move it to your prject then change the [CssManager Path line](https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/blob/master/Juice/JuiceApp.cs#L52) after you install JuiceUI. Beyond that, if you want to edit a specific part of the date picker's css, you only have to look at its class names, create your own style sheet and use those class names to manipulate what you want. You can find all the specific class names by opening your project in 
Firefox or chrome

Comment: then just right click the datepicker element you want changed, and go to "inspect element with firebug" or "inspect element" and get the class name.

BTW [here is a q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342263/juiceui-change-theme-style) about how to change the juiceui theme

Comment: @SpYk3HH This is MVC, not WebPages. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using jQuery in this instance.

Comment: @TiesonT. I never said there was?

Comment: @SpYk3HH "Don't use jQueryUI directly with ASP.Net apps." - did I misread this? JuiceUI is meant for WebForms applications, whereas the OP has this tagged as MVC, for which jQuery UI works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css") %>" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css") %>" rel="stylesheet"></script>
```

is completely and utterly incorrect. You need to use `<link>` tags in the `<head>` tag to load the CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css") %>" />
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, didn't notice that you're using the WebPages view engine - the example I had was Razor syntax.

Comment: I hadn't seen this until after I moved to Juice but thanks for clarifying what's the best way to render CSS files.